# Convert All Rows to Column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have have string H|A|100|200|300|400|500

Need to Convert string to Column as Below

| From | To | FromID | ToID | Distance1 | Distance2 | Distance3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | A | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 |

Thanks

Comment: have you tried any solution you can think of?

Comment: to be honest with you, i can't seem to understand the rule for those columns. why from H to A? why the distances are 300, 400, and 500? and so on.

Comment: i Tried below one

Comment: It's not clear what your data looks like, is it rows 1-7 or a string as in the edit?

Comment: Convert string  H|A|100|200|300|400|500 
Into table as below
From  To  FromID  ToID  Distance1  Distance2  Distance3
H         A  100         200          300                 400                    500

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: Parsing input _can_ be done in T-SQL, but that doesn't mean you _should_. I strongly recommend to take this responsibility outside. Do it in your application code. If there is no application, then a bash script or PowerShell script will do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several alternatives, if you use SQL Server 2022+ you can use the STRING_SPLIT with positional argument:

```sql
SELECT  [1] AS [From], [2] AS [To], [3] AS [FromID], [4] AS [ToID], [5] AS [Distance1], [6] AS [Distance2], [7] AS [Distance3]
FROM    STRING_SPLIT('H|A|100|200|300|400|500', '|', 1) ss
PIVOT   (MAX([value]) FOR [ordinal] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7])) pv
```

The problem with using STRING_SPLIT without the argument is that ROW_NUMBER isn't guaranteed to be in correct order (even if it probably is 99.99% of times).

For older versions (2016+) one potential solution is OPENJSON:

```sql
SELECT  [0] AS [From], [1] AS [To], [2] AS [FromID], [3] AS [ToID], [4] AS [Distance1], [5] AS [Distance2], [6] AS [Distance3]
FROM    OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE('H|A|100|200|300|400|500', '|', '","') + '"]')
PIVOT   (MAX([value]) FOR [key] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6])) pv
```

First, you convert the string into a json array, then open it up and pivoting the key values.

If your string contains special characters, you might need to do some more work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this solution a try:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'H|A|100|200|300|400|500';

WITH SplitData AS (
    SELECT
        value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, '|')
),
PivotedData AS (
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) AS 'From',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END) AS 'To',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN value END) AS 'FromID',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN value END) AS 'ToID',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN value END) AS 'Distance1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN value END) AS 'Distance2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN value END) AS 'Distance3'
    FROM SplitData
)
SELECT * FROM PivotedData;
```