In SQL, how to parse a column that contains a string of delimited text separated by a comma into individual columns, such as Prod1, Prod2, etc
In SQL, how do I parse a column PRODUCT_NAME, which has a string of delimited text separated by a comma for each product, into individual columns, such as Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, etc.
Example of the first 4 rows of data for column PRODUCT_NAME:



PRODUCT_NAME




BR2, BR0, C3


BR2, BR0, HOS - ADDL OUTLET


BR2, BR0, HOS - DIG STB, C2


BR2, BR0, HOS - DIGITAL STANDARD, C0, C3



There are 26 or more distinct products.
What I want to achieve so that I can use each Prod1, Prod2, etc. as an individual indicator or flag:



Prod1
Prod2
Prod3
Prod4
Prod5




BR2
BR0
C3




BR2
BR0
HOS - ADDL OUTLET




BR2
BR0
HOS - DIG STB
C2



BR2
BR0
HOS - DIGITAL STANDARD
C0
C3



Neither of these work.
select PARSENAME(product_name, ',') asProd1
from db.tablename


--To split the delimited values into rows: 

 Declare @NewColumn varchar (100)
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME,@NewColumn 
FROM  db.tablename
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(PRODUCT_NAME, ',');


There are going to be plenty of duplicates for this, the problem is I can't tell which as we don't have expected results or sample data. If you provide both, I, or someone else, will be able to "hammer" this appropriately.

Of course, the the real problem is your design; fix the design. Don't store delimited string in your database.

STRING_SPLIT() is going to be the best route. That will split values into their own rows, and after that you can pivot out. I would really question performing that second step though since the output from STRING_SPLIT() is going to be more relational and better to work with for most applications. Can you share why neither approach you took didn't work? Errors? Unexpected output?

This question more about PIVOT, not string_split.

@ValNik Well I don't know how it can only be about one or the other - you have to break single values up before you can pivot them.

Yes, string_split is practically mandatory here, but it is not difficult. It is usually noticeably more difficult with PIVOT. I also saw that there are suitable solutions on the link provided (already has answers).

Unfortunately, the linked "duplicate" is an old question from 2012 that contains many obsolete answers including those that create functions (no longer needed) and answers that only support a two-part split. As mentioned above, the best approach is to use STRING_SPLIT() with the enable_ordinal option set to 1 (SQL Server 2022 and later) and follow that up with a PIVOT. For earlier versions of SQL server, there is no documented way to guarantee that the original order is preserved, so a JSON-based hack may be used. See "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78106121#78106477".
